# Pandas dataframe custom forward fillna optimisation

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, pandas

I have a function that synchronizes according to some specifications columns of a `dataframe`.
**The functions works**, nevertheless I was wondering **how to**:

- **Improve performances**
- **Make it more pythonic**

Please feel free to leave any suggestions.

---

## Function specifications

1. *Inputs*:

   - **`df`** : a `dataframe` with columns:

     - `[a0,...aN]` : `a0` to `aN` names can be any valid `string` and contains `numeric` values
     - `[agent,date]` : are fixed names, `agent` contains `numeric` values and `date` contains `datetime`.
   - **`sync_with`** : The columns to synchronize with (a `string` or an `listof string` contained in `[a0,..., aN]` or, by default, an `empty list` to synchronize all the `[a0,...,aN]`.
2. *Synchronization*:

   - Do a forward `fillna` grouped by agent values.
   - Drop the rows where all columns to synchronize with values are empty
3. *Returns* : the synchronized `dataframe`

Here is my function:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def synchronize(df,sync_with=[]):
    _df = df.copy()

    if not isinstance(sync_with,list):
        sync_with = [sync_with]

    _fixed_cols = ['date','agent']
    _fixed_cols.extend(sync_with)
    _colset = [c for c in _df.columns if c not in _fixed_cols]

    for ag in _df.agent.unique():
        _df.loc[_df.agent==ag,_colset] = _df.loc[_df.agent==ag,_colset].fillna(method='ffill')
        if _sync_with:
            _df.loc[_df.agent==ag,:] = _df.loc[_df.agent==ag,:].dropna(how='all', subset=_sync_with)
            _df.loc[_df.agent==ag,:] = _df.loc[_df.agent==ag,:].fillna(method='ffill')

    return _df.dropna(how='all', subset=_sync_with)
```

## Sample

```
foo = pd.DataFrame(dict(date=pd.to_datetime(['2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2010', '2013', '2015', '2016']),
                        agent=[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                        _a=[1, np.nan, np.nan, 4, 5, np.nan, 7, 8],
                        _b=[11, 22, np.nan, np.nan, 55, np.nan, 77, np.nan],
                        _c=[111, np.nan, 333, np.nan, np.nan, 666, 777, np.nan]))
```

## Results

```
# 1. default (13 ms per loop)
print(synchronize(foo))
    _a    _b     _c  agent       date
0  1.0  11.0  111.0      1 2010-01-01
1  1.0  22.0  111.0      1 2011-01-01
2  1.0  22.0  333.0      1 2012-01-01
3  4.0  22.0  333.0      1 2013-01-01
4  5.0  55.0    NaN      2 2010-01-01
5  5.0  55.0  666.0      2 2013-01-01
6  7.0  77.0  777.0      2 2015-01-01
7  8.0  77.0  777.0      2 2016-01-01

# 2. sync with one column (35 ms per loop)
print(synchronize(foo,'_c'))
    _a    _b     _c  agent       date
0  1.0  11.0  111.0      1 2010-01-01
2  1.0  22.0  333.0      1 2012-01-01
5  5.0  55.0  666.0      2 2013-01-01
6  7.0  77.0  777.0      2 2015-01-01

# 3. sync with two columns (35 ms per loop)
print(synchronize(foo,['_a','_b']))
    _a    _b     _c  agent       date
0  1.0  11.0  111.0      1 2010-01-01
1  1.0  22.0  111.0      1 2011-01-01
3  4.0  22.0  333.0      1 2013-01-01
4  5.0  55.0    NaN      2 2010-01-01
6  7.0  77.0  777.0      2 2015-01-01
7  8.0  77.0  777.0      2 2016-01-01
```

Comment: When I follow what you your explanation says, in test case 2, row 5 should read `5  5.0  55.0  666.0`. Which is correct?

Comment: It is correct, will check as soon as possible my code to correct it, thanks.

Comment: Have to find why my `_df.loc[_df.agent==ag,_colset]` skip the index 4...

Comment: It's ok, I corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a few ways to make it more pythonic

## 'private' variables

variable within a function are limited to the scope of that function, so prepending them with a `_` is unnecessary

## lists

`sync_with` could also be another Container, like a `tuple` or so. Only when it is a `str` you need to convert it.

also be aware of what can go wrong with [mutable default arguments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments). They are instantiated at the moment of function definition. In this case they are not appended to in the function or returned, so it should not pose any problems, but I try to avoid them anyway

`fixed_cols` can then be assembled like this:

```
fixed_cols = ['agent', 'date'] + list(sync_with)
```

Then only if `sync_with` is an generator, something can go wrong, so I would do something like this:

```
def synchronize(df, sync_with=None):
    if sync_with is None:
        sync_with = []
    elif isinstance(sync_with, str):
        sync_with = [sync_with, ]
    else:
        sync_with = list(sync_with)
```

## performance

- Making a copy initially is unnecessary, unless you will perform operations inplace on the `df`
- You can use `DataFrame.groupby.transform`, and then select the rows which had any non-null value in the original df

You would get something like this:

```
def synchronize3(df,sync_with=[]):
    if isinstance(sync_with, str):
        sync_with = [sync_with, ]
    else:
        sync_with = list(sync_with)
    result = df.groupby('agent').transform(lambda x: x.fillna(method='ffill'))
    if sync_with:
        result = result.loc[pd.notnull(df[sync_with]).any(axis=1), :]
    result = result.assign(agent=df['agent']).reindex(columns=df.columns)
    return result
```

## Results:

```
%timeit synchronize(foo)
```

> ```
> 9.48 ms ± 527 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
> ```

```
%timeit synchronize(foo,'_c')
```

> ```
> 29 ms ± 817 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
> ```

```
%timeit synchronize(foo,['_a','_b'])
```

> ```
> 27.8 ms ± 608 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
> ```

```
assert synchronize(foo).equals(synchronize3(foo))
%timeit synchronize3(foo)
```

> ```
> 5.71 ms ± 935 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
>
>
>   _a  _b  _c  agent   date
> 0 1.0 11.0    111.0   1   2010-01-01
> 1 1.0 22.0    111.0   1   2011-01-01
> 2 1.0 22.0    333.0   1   2012-01-01
> 3 4.0 22.0    333.0   1   2013-01-01
> 4 5.0 55.0    NaN     2   2010-01-01
> 5 5.0 55.0    666.0   2   2013-01-01
> 6 7.0 77.0    777.0   2   2015-01-01
> 7 8.0 77.0    777.0   2   2016-01-01
> ```

```
assert synchronize(foo,'_c').equals(synchronize3(foo,'_c'))
%timeit synchronize3(foo,'_c')
```

> ```
> 6.41 ms ± 131 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
>
>   _a  _b  _c  agent   date
> 0 1.0 11.0    111.0   1   2010-01-01
> 2 1.0 22.0    333.0   1   2012-01-01
> 5 5.0 55.0    666.0   2   2013-01-01
> 6 7.0 77.0    777.0   2   2015-01-01
> ```

```
assert synchronize(foo,['_a','_b']).equals(synchronize3(foo,['_a','_b']))
%timeit synchronize3(foo,['_a','_b'])
```

> ```
> 7.33 ms ± 1.16 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
>
> _a    _b  _c  agent   date
> 0 1.0 11.0    111.0   1   2010-01-01
> 1 1.0 22.0    111.0   1   2011-01-01
> 3 4.0 22.0    333.0   1   2013-01-01
> 4 5.0 55.0    NaN     2   2010-01-01
> 6 7.0 77.0    777.0   2   2015-01-01
> 7 8.0 77.0    777.0   2   2016-01-01
> ```

## bugfixes

the version of your algorithm I used was this:

```
def synchronize(df,sync_with=[]):
    _df = df.copy()

    if not isinstance(sync_with,list):
        sync_with = [sync_with]

    _fixed_cols = ['date','agent']
    _fixed_cols.extend(sync_with)
    _colset = [c for c in _df.columns if c not in _fixed_cols]

    for ag in _df.agent.unique():
        _df.loc[_df.agent==ag,_colset] = _df.loc[_df.agent==ag,_colset].fillna(method='ffill')
        if sync_with:
            _df.loc[_df.agent==ag,:] = _df.loc[_df.agent==ag,:].dropna(how='all', subset=sync_with)
            _df.loc[_df.agent==ag,:] = _df.loc[_df.agent==ag,:].fillna(method='ffill')
    if sync_with:
        _df = _df.dropna(how='all', subset=sync_with)
    return _df.astype({'agent': 'int64'})  # else the `dtype` is different from the one in my method, throwing of the assertions
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, will have a look as soon as possible and let you know. Just for the first part and the use of  `_` for private I knew but it is used to ease the read of my code, as a convention.